# slapd slow to return results when filter consists of only one letter + wildcard

Tags: openldap

My OpenLDAP instance is slow to return records when a filter of one letter and a wildcard (*) are used on a field with a substring index. When the filter has more than one letter, the search is very fast. My question is why?

The scenario is OpenLDAP v.2.4.44, LMDB back-end, OS X, 1.3 million records, index set as:

```
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: cn eq,sub
```

If the search filter is *'(cn=s*)'*, the query takes a long time, whereas if the filter is *'(cn=sm*)'* it's blazing fast. Running **slapindex** makes no difference.

Here are some numbers, using **time**:

```
$time ldapsearch -H ldap:/// -D cn=Manager,dc=xyz,dc=com -w secret -b dc=xyz,dc=com -s sub -z 5 '(cn=s*)' cn sn

-- some ldap records --

real    0m0.474s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Changing to *'(cn=sm*)'* yields:

```
real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

To *'(cn=smi*)'*:

```
real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

In fact, those times remain constant once the filter has more than one letter and the wildcard.

Investigating further, I found that going down the alphabet results in progressively longer times, but only for that one letter search.

Going with *'(cn=a*)'* gives:

```
real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

*'(cn=b*)'*:

```
real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s
```

At this point, you can see user and sys are always fast, so I'll omit them from now on, and only show real times. Thus:

```
'(cn=a*)' --> 0m0.012s
'(cn=b*)' --> 0m0.046s
'(cn=c*)' --> 0m0.105s
'(cn=d*)' --> 0m0.149s
'(cn=e*)' --> 0m0.174s
...
'(cn=m*)' --> 0m0.342s
...
'(cn=s*)' --> 0m0.523s
...
'(cn=z*)' --> 0m0.606s
```

But if any of these searches are given an additional letter, it's back to fast (0.012s is the avg). So for some reason, **slapd** is taking a long time to find that first letter, but only if one letter is used.

Upon even further investigation, filtering on the 'sn' attribute (e.g. 'sn=s*'), which is NOT indexed, yields the same times as the indexed 'cn' attribute, when using one letter + wildcard filters. Thus, **slapd** appears to be ignoring the substring index on the 'cn' attribute when filtering for one letter + wildcard. However, adding a second letter makes the 'cn' filter fast whereas the 'sn' filter remains slow, which is to be expected.

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this behavior is by design. OpenLDAP has a global setting that controls the minimum length for a substring index. The default minimum number of characters that get indexed in a substring index is 2.

If you use online configuration (OLC), you will find the description of the setting in **man slapd-config**:

> **olcIndexSubstrIfMinlen**: <integer>
>      Specify the minimum length for subinitial and subfinal indices. An attribute value must have at least this many characters in order to be processed by the indexing functions. The default is 2.

Or, if you use the traditional configuration method, you will find its description in **man slapd.conf**:

> **index_substr_if_minlen**: <integer>
>      Specify the minimum length for subinitial and subfinal indices. An attribute value must have at least this many characters in order to be processed by the indexing functions. The default is 2.

The **man** pages additionally say:

> Options described in this section apply to all backends, unless specifically overridden in a backend definition.

Does anyone know if this behavior can be overridden at the attribute level? It would be great if substring min and max lengths can be specified at a more granular level than global or per backend.